# Why std::iterator is not able to access the function

Tags: c++, vector, stl, c++14

When I try to access a function through iterator the compile tells that class ha no member with such name.

```
class Director
{
private:
    std::string stdstrName;
public:
    Director(std::string name): stdstrName(name){ }
    void setName(std::string name) { stdstrName = name; }
    std::string getName() { return stdstrName; }

};

int main(){    
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Director>> stdVecDir;
    std::shared_ptr<Director> pointer1 = std::make_shared<Director>("Director1");
    std::shared_ptr<Director> pointer2 = std::make_shared<Director>("Director2");
    std::shared_ptr<Director> pointer3 = std::make_shared<Director>("Director3");
    stdVecDir.push_back(pointer1);
    stdVecDir.push_back(pointer2);
    stdVecDir.push_back(pointer3);
    auto it = std::find(stdVecDir.begin(), stdVecDir.end(), [](std::shared_ptr<Director> dir) { return dir->getName() == "Director2"; });
    if (it != std::end(stdVecDir))
        std::cout << *it->getName();  // compiler complains that getName() is not a member of class Director
}
```

Why does the compile complains that getName() is not a member of class Director.

Comment: It's an [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) issue. `*it->getName()` is equal to `*(it->getName())`. You need `(*it)->getName()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `std::find()`, but it's used with values, not with callables, hence you need to use `std::find_if`.

And you are using your iterator to access to a member function of an object pointed to by a pointer which is pointed to by an iterator, hence you have two dereferences, not one.

The following is a correction

```
auto it = std::find_if(stdVecDir.begin(), stdVecDir.end(),
                        [](std::shared_ptr <Director> dir) { return dir->getName() == "Director2"; });
    if (it != std::end(stdVecDir))
        std::cout << it->get()->getName(); //or (*it)->getName();
```

Answer (score 1):

If im not mistaken you need to change it to (*it)-> to access Director from iterator and shared_ptr. With *it-> you are accessing shared_ptr from the iterator.